# How to require php sessions?

Tags: php, session

Hi I want to require a session that is set to 1 when my users pass the verify page eg: they have logged in. How would I require that session to be set , here is my code ,

```
if(isset($_SESSION['logged_in']==1)){

}else{

header('login.html');
exit;
}
```

Thnks in advanced,
Caolan.

Comment: Just like that. What's your question?

Comment: I have no Idea it doesn't work for some reoson

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make little correction like this

```
if(isset($_SESSION['logged_in']) && $_SESSION['logged_in']==1)
{
  //some code
}
else
{
  header('location:login.html');
  exit;
}
```